# fibonacci sequence with while

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I tried to write fibonacci sequence in JS.

I could get result

```
var x = 0;
var y = 1;
var result = 0;
while (result<100){

result=x+y;
x = y;
y = result;
document.write("This is next number "+result+"<br>")
}
console.log(result)
```

I wonder if it is  possible to get result with this while(total and count) loop like this one?

```
var total = 0, count = 1;
while(count <= 10){
total += count;
count += 1;
}
console.log(total);
```

Comment: Did you run into any issues with it? I am not a JS interpreter myself.

Comment: If you are using a loop, you will need to keep track of more things, just like in the first code block. You may find this link useful for computing the total based on the count: http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibFormula.html

Answer (score 0):

No it isn't possible, the second one will give you quadratic polynomial values.

There are however various ways to calculate the nth fibonacci nummber without calculating the previous ones. One way is using matrix multiplication, the other is using a real-valued formula with roots where the reals happen to be integers.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = 0, y = 1;
var count = 2 ;
var fib ;
while(count++ <=10){
    var fib = x+y ;
    x = y ;
    y = fib;
}
console.log(fib);
```

Comment: some explaining for the lady pls...?

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate one of the outer variables for an additional subtraction:

```
var x = 0;
var y = 1;
while(y < 100) {
    y += x;
    x = y - x;
}
// result is y
```

To see that this is correct compare the above to using a temporary:

```
var x = 0;
var y = 1;
while(y < 100) {
    var tmp = x + y;
    x = y;   // = tmp - x
    y = tmp;
}
// result is y
```

If you want the counter, then an extra variable is the only way*:

```
var x = 0;
var y = 1;
// you can define fib(0) either 1 or 0, this is fib(0) := 1
for(var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    y += x;
    x = y - x;
}
// result is y
```

(* unless you use the closed form for fib(n))

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:-

```
var fib = function(n){
var a=0,b=1,f=1,i=2;
var arr =[];
while(f<n){
arr.push(f);
f=a+b;
a=b;
b=f;
i++;
}
return arr;
}
var fibArr = fib(20);
console.log(fibArr);// returns array of fibonacci
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Count is just the number position right? next number is sum of previous two number right .  Here on your second code its just the sum of previos number with the position.

Comment: this should definitely be a comment!